# Zipping documentation generated with Enunciate

Tags: maven, enunciate

I'm using Enunciate as a Maven plugin for API documentation generation. I want the generated documentation to be zipped, and so far couldn't find a way to do this. The documentation is generated, but in a directory and not in a zip file.
Here is an excerpt from my pom:

```
            <plugin>
            <!-- auto-generate docs for REST API -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>enunciate.xml</configFile>
                <!-- the directory where to put the docs -->
                <docsDir>${project.parent.basedir}/VrmMisc/Docs/SMA_API</docsDir>
                <!-- <docsSubdir>${project.parent.basedir}/VrmMisc/Docs/SMA_API</docsSubdir> -->

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>docs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The dependency:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>enunciate-rt</artifactId>
        <version>${enunciate.plugin.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>enunciate-jaxws-ri-rt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>enunciate-jersey-rt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using Enunciate version 1.26.2.

Comment: Have you tried to configure the to `goal` to be `assemble`? e.g. `<goal>assemble</goal>`

Answer (score 2):

If you tell Enunciate to "export" the "docs" artifact to a *file* (instead of a directory) Enunciate will zip it up for you:

```
    <plugin>
        <!-- auto-generate docs for REST API -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <configFile>enunciate.xml</configFile>
            <exports>
                <docs>${project.parent.basedir}/VrmMisc/Docs/SMA_API.zip</docs>
            </exports>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>docs</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to run a Shell command to make a WAR file easily deployable on Tomcat

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=enunciate.war
directory=enunciate_directory
echo $filename building starts ...
cd $directory
jar -cf $filename *
```